# How to get the input from a touch screen from individual pixels?

Tags: android

I am creating a paint app for android, I have a doubt when we touch the display, can we get the input pixel by pixel to make the painting more accurate. Any one help me how to get pixel by pixel input ?

Comment: you can implement onTouch and listen to touch events, which has x and y to represent the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set an `OnTouchListener` on your canvas view and get the x & y coordinates from there.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            //Here you can do whatever you need with the coordinates
            int xPos = event.getX();
            int yPos = event.getY();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I use it to get a series of input from the touch digitizer ??